# Error Executing DDL via JDBC statement in Spring Boot 2, Hibernate, PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, heroku, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I wanted to connect to Heroku cloud with my Spring boot 2.0.6 application using PostgreSQL but I'm getting an exception. It seemed to work fine in Spring boot 1, so it might be a Spring boot 2 problem. I've tried modifying my applicaton.properties in different ways but none of them succeeded.

My log:

```
2018-10-26 09:56:14.762  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] com.greenenergy.GreenEnergyApplication   : Starting GreenEnergyApplication on localhost.localdomain with PID 7536 (/home/alexanderp/Projects/greenenergy/greenenergy/target/classes started by alexanderp in /home/alexanderp/Projects/greenenergy/greenenergy)
2018-10-26 09:56:14.764  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] com.greenenergy.GreenEnergyApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-10-26 09:56:14.821  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6c532aae: startup date [Fri Oct 26 09:56:14 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-10-26 09:56:15.861  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5e1ea8db] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-10-26 09:56:16.254  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-10-26 09:56:16.273  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-10-26 09:56:16.273  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.34
2018-10-26 09:56:16.277  INFO 7536 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.16] using APR version [1.6.3].
2018-10-26 09:56:16.278  INFO 7536 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
2018-10-26 09:56:16.278  INFO 7536 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
2018-10-26 09:56:16.280  INFO 7536 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.0h-fips  27 Mar 2018]
2018-10-26 09:56:16.332  INFO 7536 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-10-26 09:56:16.332  INFO 7536 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1513 ms
2018-10-26 09:56:16.392  INFO 7536 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-10-26 09:56:16.396  INFO 7536 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-10-26 09:56:16.396  INFO 7536 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-10-26 09:56:16.396  INFO 7536 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-10-26 09:56:16.396  INFO 7536 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-10-26 09:56:16.585  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-10-26 09:56:17.412  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-10-26 09:56:17.452  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-10-26 09:56:17.465  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-10-26 09:56:17.531  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
2018-10-26 09:56:17.532  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-10-26 09:56:17.564  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-10-26 09:56:17.655  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
2018-10-26 09:56:17.667  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
2018-10-26 09:56:17.668  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@289d236a
2018-10-26 09:56:18.172  WARN 7536 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:375) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applyConstraintDropping(SchemaDropperImpl.java:331) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:230) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:112) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:144) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1753) [spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1690) [spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) [spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) [spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1087) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at com.greenenergy.GreenEnergyApplication.main(GreenEnergyApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "story" does not exist
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:307) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:293) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:270) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:266) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 40 common frames omitted

2018-10-26 09:56:18.223  WARN 7536 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
2018-10-26 09:56:18.223  WARN 7536 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : table "blogger" does not exist, skipping
2018-10-26 09:56:18.274  WARN 7536 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
2018-10-26 09:56:18.275  WARN 7536 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : table "story" does not exist, skipping
2018-10-26 09:56:18.326  WARN 7536 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
2018-10-26 09:56:18.326  WARN 7536 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : sequence "hibernate_sequence" does not exist, skipping
2018-10-26 09:56:18.553  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@504b3d51'
2018-10-26 09:56:18.560  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-10-26 09:56:19.294  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-10-26 09:56:19.526  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6c532aae: startup date [Fri Oct 26 09:56:14 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-10-26 09:56:19.552  WARN 7536 --- [  restartedMain] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2018-10-26 09:56:19.576  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public java.lang.String com.greenenergy.controller.ErrorPageController.error(org.springframework.ui.Model,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-10-26 09:56:19.577  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String com.greenenergy.controller.HomeController.stories(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2018-10-26 09:56:19.578  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/story]}" onto public java.lang.String com.greenenergy.controller.HomeController.story(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2018-10-26 09:56:19.578  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/title/{title}]}" onto public java.lang.String com.greenenergy.controller.HomeController.searchForUser(java.lang.String,org.springframework.ui.Model) throws java.lang.Exception
2018-10-26 09:56:19.610  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-10-26 09:56:19.610  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-10-26 09:56:19.624  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in exceptionGeneral
2018-10-26 09:56:19.889  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2018-10-26 09:56:19.919  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-10-26 09:56:19.920  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-10-26 09:56:19.927  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2018-10-26 09:56:19.952  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-10-26 09:56:19.958  INFO 7536 --- [  restartedMain] com.greenenergy.GreenEnergyApplication   : Started GreenEnergyApplication in 5.487 seconds (JVM running for 6.095)
```

My application.properties file:

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.mvc.locale-resolver=fixed
#spring.mvc.locale=en

spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://ec2-54-246-86-167.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/d3k8k2dts7f4ih?ssl=true;sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
spring.datasource.username=tizzwuqydagwmm
spring.datasource.password=9a88893d6eed1e5c334c2978735eaa273b0458ceefe18c2a439aaab45af9f72c
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

My entity class:

```
package com.greenenergy.domain;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity
public class Story {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private Date posted;
    @ManyToOne
    private Blogger blogger;

    private Story() {

    }

    public Story(String title, String content, Date posted, Blogger blogger) {
        super();
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
        this.posted = posted;
        this.blogger = blogger;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Date getPosted() {
        return posted;
    }

    public void setPosted(Date posted) {
        this.posted = posted;
    }

    public Blogger getBlogger() {
        return blogger;
    }

    public void setBlogger(Blogger blogger) {
        this.blogger = blogger;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Story [title=" + title + ", content=" + content + ", posted=" + posted + ", blogger=" + blogger + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: Please enable debug for "org.hibernate" to see if they give you more information on that.

Answer (score 0):

Debug log:

```
2018-10-26 10:25:56.613 DEBUG 12082 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister     :  Delete 0: delete from blogger where id=?
2018-10-26 10:25:56.642 DEBUG 12082 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.l.p.b.i.spaces.QuerySpacesImpl       : Adding QuerySpace : uid = <gen:0> -> org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.EntityQuerySpaceImpl@46fc130]
2018-10-26 10:25:56.644 DEBUG 12082 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.p.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker   : Visiting attribute path : age
2018-10-26 10:25:56.644 DEBUG 12082 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.p.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker   : Visiting attribute path : name
2018-10-26 10:25:56.644 DEBUG 12082 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.p.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker   : Visiting attribute path : stories
2018-10-26 10:25:56.649 DEBUG 12082 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.l.p.b.i.spaces.QuerySpacesImpl       : Adding QuerySpace : uid = <gen:1> -> org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.CollectionQuerySpaceImpl@4106511d]
2018-10-26 10:25:56.652 DEBUG 12082 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.l.p.b.i.spaces.QuerySpacesImpl       : Adding QuerySpace : uid = <gen:2> -> org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.EntityQuerySpaceImpl@105c3ae5]
2018-10-26 10:25:56.653 DEBUG 12082 --- [  restartedMain] lanBuildingAssociationVisitationStrategy : Building LoadPlan...
2018-10-26 10:25:56.665 DEBUG 12082 --- [  restartedMain] h.l.p.e.i.LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor : processing queryspace <gen:0>
2018-10-26 10:25:56.671 DEBUG 12082 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.l.p.build.spi.LoadPlanTreePrinter    : LoadPlan(entity=com.greenenergy.domain.Blogger)
    - Returns
       - EntityReturnImpl(entity=com.greenenergy.domain.Blogger, querySpaceUid=<gen:0>, path=com.greenenergy.domain.Blogger)
          - CollectionAttributeFetchImpl(collection=com.greenenergy.domain.Blogger.stories, querySpaceUid=<gen:1>, path=com.greenenergy.domain.Blogger.stories)
             - (collection element) CollectionFetchableElementEntityGraph(entity=com.greenenergy.domain.Story, querySpaceUid=<gen:2>, path=com.greenenergy.domain.Blogger.stories.<elements>)
    - QuerySpaces
       - EntityQuerySpaceImpl(uid=<gen:0>, entity=com.greenenergy.domain.Blogger)
          - SQL table alias mapping - blogger0_
          - alias suffix - 0_
          - suffixed key columns - {id1_0_0_}
```